# Is it Okay to consume repositories and services from a same controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use repositories to perform basic CRUD operations and I use services to implement business logic with these repositories.

I tend to use repositories and services at the same time within controllers. My question is -is this Okay in terms of a standard architecture? Should I move my basic repositories to basic services, so my controllers only consume services, not repositories? Hope this make sense, thank you.

Comment: Does it make sense to have your services call the repositories directly, or is there good reason to have them both function entirely independently?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338816/should-controllers-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-app-call-repositories-services-or-both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to put your Repositories behind the Services, so the Controllers would only consume Services. That way you:

- Maintain nice layered architecture (Onion Architecture pattern);
- Keep your Controllers Actions clean and clear.

Actually, nothing stops you from injecting Repos along with Services into your Controllers but it just feels wrong - what is the point of Services existence then?

Comment: You don't *need* services for smaller projects.  I do recommend injecting the Repositories into your controller if you're not going to use services, but the pattern isn't MVCS, it's MVC.

Comment: @George, sure, it depends on project size but in practice we didn't have such a simple project that need no services at all. Its probably always a matter of how you build your Domain. We avoid an anemic domain, our entities contain logic but just that directly related to domain. Every "service-like" logic is in App Services.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK as long as you don't put any biz logic in the controller. There's no point in creating a new service class that wraps the repository if it doesn't add any logic/behavior.

> I tend to use repositories and
>   services at the same time within
>   controllers.

Think about the controller/action functionality and it's dependencies, if you are using repositories and services then you should probably create a new service class that wraps the functionality, and make the controller/action depend on that single service. Actions should ideally depend on one service only.

I've had controllers call repositories directly when all I need is CRUD (e.g. admin app).